# Забрать последнюю строку в триггере Insert MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, триггер

При выполнении триггера каждый раз записывается вся таблица. Не получается организовать выборку только последней введенной строки, помогите пожалуйста. :(

Рабочий вариант который забирает всю таблицу каждый раз при срабатывании:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Авторизация_INSERT
ON Авторизация
After INSERT
AS
Begin
    INSERT INTO Журнал(Событие)
    SELECT N'Добавлен пользователь: ' + Логин + N'   Пароль: ' + Пароль
    FROM Авторизация
END;
```

Comment: Вам, по-видимому, вместо `FROM Авторизация` нужно `FROM INSERTED` использовать.

Comment: @i-one Спасибо большое, помогло.